# Номер, но нумеровать

Tags: орфография, этимология

На одном из сайтов я встретил слово "номеровать". Видимо, была опечатка, но какая же она приятная уху! Интересно, почему "номер" превратился в "нумер"? Что это - дань латинскому "numerum"?

Comment: Некая вариативность.
Ноль - нуль
тоннель - туннель
борт - буртик
спорт - спурт (??)


Comment: Буртик? Спурт? Что это за слова такие?

Comment: Это нормальные слова, но с другим значением. Они не парные к борту и тем более к спорту.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Номеровать" последнее время было редким вариантом к "нумеровать". Исходным же вариантом для обоих слов (номер/нумер и нумеровать) я полагаю вариант с У: нумер, нумерация, нумеровать. Если так, то появление парного "номер" можно объяснить:
а) Общей тенденцией замены У на О (в определенных позицях, часто - перед и после М, Н, Р и Л): тоннель<туннель, эксплотация<эксплутация, банкрот<банкрут и т.д.
б) Влиянием английского, где звук произносится как очень краткому полуоткрытое А, (=безударному русскому О, хотя в английском оно ударное). 
в) Случайными причинами. Подробности опускаю.

Answer (score 1):

Не думаю, что на сайте была ошибка. Слово "номеровать" словарное, оно есть и у Ушакова, и в современном словаре Ефремовой. Здесь действительно то, что называется вариативностью.

Comment: Странно, но я перед отправкой вопроса посмотрел словарь Ожегова и 4-томный словарь Института русского языка АН СССР. Ни в одном из них нет слова "номеровать". Кстати, в академическом словаре к слову "номер" дается с пометой "устар." слово "нумер". Может быть, отголоски этого слова и сохранились в слове "нумеровать"?

Comment: Да, забыл. И на "Грамота.ру"набирал слово "номеровать". Ответ - "искомое слово отсутствует"

Comment: http://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/ushakov/887074

Comment: Спасибо, Валентин! Для меня это новость. Даже стыдно признаться на старости лет. Я знаю, что я ничего не знаю.

Answer (score 1):

Это так же, как ноль и нуль. Оба слова одинаково употребительны.
Есть такое слово - "прономеровать" (словарь Ушакова). Думаю, что и "номеровать" имеет право на существование.

Comment: У меня с нулем всегда проблемы. В именительном падеже - вроде "Ноль" нормально звучит. Но вот "нолем", "ноля" как-то не ложится на ухо.  (особенно было заметно, когда писала статью о нуле, единице и других крайних понятиях математики). Я уж везде на "нуль" перешла.